# While using a list data view how can I get the total number of list items that match the current filters?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem

While viewing a List data view I want to show the total number of items, but also have that number be updated when for example the user applies filters to the view.

This is so users can quickly find out how many items have arbitrary values like a status of "New" and a create date of "10/26/2017". These queries are dynamic and arbitrary so just creating separate views would not work.

I thought maybe something with the client object model, but I can't seem to sort out how to get this information without hacking together a solution that finds all the current filters and manually runs a REST call to get the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the view setting and choose the `Total` section.

Here select a column(field) that has no empty values.

Example -

[image]